# Count phrases frequency in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

The data I have is stored in a pandas dataframe - please see a reproducible example below. The real dataframe will have more than 10k lines and a lot more ords / phrases per line.
I'd like to count the number of times each two-word phrase appears in column `ReviewContent`. If this were a text file and not the column of a dataframe I would use NLTK's Collocations module (something along the lines of answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691816/counting-phrases-in-python-using-nltk) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920572/counting-phrase-frequency-in-python-3-3-2) ). My question is: how can I transform column `ReviewContent` into a single corpus text?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'ReviewContent' : ['Great food',
'Low prices but above average food',
'Staff was the worst',
'Great location and great food',
'Really low prices',
'The daily menu is usually great',
'I waited a long time to be served, but it was worth it. Great food']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Expected output:

```
[(('great', 'food'), 3), (('low', 'prices'), 2), ...]
```

or

```
[('great food', 3), ('low prices', 2)...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a sequence/iterable, `df["ReviewContent"]` is structured exactly the same as the result of applying `nltk.sent_tokenize()` to a file of text: A list of strings containing one sentence each. So just use it the same way.

```
counts = collections.Counter()
for sent in df["ReviewContent"]:
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
    counts.update(nltk.bigrams(words))
```

If you aren't sure what to do next, that's not connected to using a dataframe. For counting bigrams you don't need the `collocations` module, just `nltk.bigrams()` and a counting dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using join:

```
corpus = ' '.join(df.ReviewContent)
```

Here's the result:

```
In [102]: corpus
Out[102]: 'Great food Low prices but above average food Staff was the worst Great location and great food Really low prices The daily menu is usually great I waited a long time to be served, but it was worth it. Great food'
```

Comment: That would work but it would create "artificial" phrases - the last word of a review joined with the first word of the next review. I could probably workaround this somehow - if I don't receive a better answer I'll certainly choose this one.

Comment: Hopefully my answer gets at your question "how can I transform column ReviewContent into a single corpus text?" I agree about the downside of artificial phrases and wonder how others handle this. In the past, I've tried joining the text with an indicator symbol like `~` instead of a space, and then use `finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(corpus)` followed by a filter to remove the artificial phrases: `finder.apply_word_filter(lambda w: w == '~')`, based on this example code: http://www.nltk.org/howto/collocations.html.

Answer (score 1):

Using Pandas version 0.20.1+, you can create SparseDataFrame directly from sparse matrixes:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

cv = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))

r = pd.SparseDataFrame(cv.fit_transform(df.ReviewContent), 
                       columns=cv.get_feature_names(),
                       index=df.index,
                       default_fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
In [52]: r
Out[52]:
   above average  and great  average food  be served  but above  but it  daily menu  great food  great location  \
0              0          0             0          0          0       0           0           1               0
1              1          0             1          0          1       0           0           0               0
2              0          0             0          0          0       0           0           0               0
3              0          1             0          0          0       0           0           1               1
4              0          0             0          0          0       0           0           0               0
5              0          0             0          0          0       0           1           0               0
6              0          0             0          1          0       1           0           1               0

   is usually    ...     staff was  the daily  the worst  time to  to be  usually great  waited long  was the  was worth  \
0           0    ...             0          0          0        0      0              0            0        0          0
1           0    ...             0          0          0        0      0              0            0        0          0
2           0    ...             1          0          1        0      0              0            0        1          0
3           0    ...             0          0          0        0      0              0            0        0          0
4           0    ...             0          0          0        0      0              0            0        0          0
5           1    ...             0          1          0        0      0              1            0        0          0
6           0    ...             0          0          0        1      1              0            1        0          1

   worth it
0         0
1         0
2         0
3         0
4         0
5         0
6         1

[7 rows x 29 columns]
```

---

If you simply want to concatenate the strings from all rows into a single one, use [Series.str.cat()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) method:

```
text = df.ReviewContent.str.cat(sep=' ')
```

Result:

```
In [57]: print(text)
Great food Low prices but above average food Staff was the worst Great location and great food Really low prices The daily me
nu is usually great I waited a long time to be served, but it was worth it. Great food
```